# Xampp does not recognize a lot of files and folders

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp

This is the project's on VSCode, the red tagged files and folders are examples... >>>
[image: Project's Folder Structure]].
I use CodeIgniter as my framework to **PHP 7.4**

Files and folders missing (like "**app**" folder) on "**runaci**" folder >>>
[image: Xamp's result]

I've already tryed reboot the server and installed **Wamp** aswell.

It should show and the folders "**web**" and "**app**" where my main files are in.

Comment: It seems likely that you have multiple "AMBAR" folders.  Notice for example that in VSCode, "AMBAR" is all capitalized but in your XAMPP directory it's all lower case.  Try going to your XAMPP phpinfo, see where it thinks your htdocs folder lives, and compare that to your VSCode. http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php